# Extract prefix (city name) from column title and place in new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
 #   Column                Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------                --------------  -----         
 0   time                  8763 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 1   Madrid_wind_speed     8763 non-null   float64       
 2   Valencia_wind_deg     8763 non-null   object        
 3   Bilbao_rain_1h        8763 non-null   float64       
 4   Valencia_wind_speed   8763 non-null   float64       
 5   Seville_humidity      8763 non-null   float64       
 6   Madrid_humidity       8763 non-null   float64       
 7   Bilbao_clouds_all     8763 non-null   float64       
 8   Bilbao_wind_speed     8763 non-null   float64       
 9   Seville_clouds_all    8763 non-null   float64       
 10  Bilbao_wind_deg       8763 non-null   float64       
 11  Barcelona_wind_speed  8763 non-null   float64       
 12  Barcelona_wind_deg    8763 non-null   float64       
 13  Madrid_clouds_all     8763 non-null   float64       
 14  Seville_wind_speed    8763 non-null   float64       
 15  Barcelona_rain_1h     8763 non-null   float64       
 16  Seville_pressure      8763 non-null   object        
 17  Seville_rain_1h       8763 non-null   float64       
 18  Bilbao_snow_3h        8763 non-null   float64       
 19  Barcelona_pressure    8763 non-null   float64       
 20  Seville_rain_3h       8763 non-null   float64       
 21  Madrid_rain_1h        8763 non-null   float64       
 22  Barcelona_rain_3h     8763 non-null   float64       
 23  Valencia_snow_3h      8763 non-null   float64       
 24  Madrid_weather_id     8763 non-null   float64       
 25  Barcelona_weather_id  8763 non-null   float64       
 26  Bilbao_pressure       8763 non-null   float64       
 27  Seville_weather_id    8763 non-null   float64       
 28  Valencia_pressure     6695 non-null   float64       
 29  Seville_temp_max      8763 non-null   float64       
 30  Madrid_pressure       8763 non-null   float64       
 31  Valencia_temp_max     8763 non-null   float64       
 32  Valencia_temp         8763 non-null   float64       
 33  Bilbao_weather_id     8763 non-null   float64       
 34  Seville_temp          8763 non-null   float64       
 35  Valencia_humidity     8763 non-null   float64       
 36  Valencia_temp_min     8763 non-null   float64       
 37  Barcelona_temp_max    8763 non-null   float64       
 38  Madrid_temp_max       8763 non-null   float64       
 39  Barcelona_temp        8763 non-null   float64       
 40  Bilbao_temp_min       8763 non-null   float64       
 41  Bilbao_temp           8763 non-null   float64       
 42  Barcelona_temp_min    8763 non-null   float64       
 43  Bilbao_temp_max       8763 non-null   float64       
 44  Seville_temp_min      8763 non-null   float64       
 45  Madrid_temp           8763 non-null   float64       
 46  Madrid_temp_min       8763 non-null   float64       
 47  load_shortfall_3h     8763 non-null   float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(45), object(2)
```

How would I go about to extract the City name from Column name and place them in a new column and merge the Wind_speed, rain_1h, etc. data into their own respective columns?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for create MultiIndex first by not splitted columns names and then use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for columns names by cities:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['time','load_shortfall_3h'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', n=1, expand=True)
df1 = df1.rename_axis([None, 'type'], axis=1).stack().reset_index()
```

Comment: i would like to have the following columns: 'time', 'load_shortfall_3h', CITY, wind_speed, wind_deg, rain_1hr, rain_3h, weather_id, snow_3h, temp, temp_min, temp max, humidity, pressure, etc.

Comment: @Pangaman89 - then use `df1 = df1.rename_axis([None, 'type'], axis=1).stack(0).reset_index()`